# Actual selfmate in OTB game?

Tags: selfmate

Danger, Will Robinson, in both English and German "selfmate" is occasionally used for what problemists correctly term "helpmate". I mean selfmate: a move so idiotic it *forces* the opponent to mate. (I quickly browsed Krabbe's site, but to no avail.)

So, did a true selfmate ever occur in an (earnest) game? A cross-check mechanism might do the trick most easily.

Comment: [This answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/32331/35006) by Robert Gamble might help.  Robert found such an OTB game between GM Danilo Milanovic and IM Jasmin Bejtovic at the [41st Bosna Open in Sarajevo 2011](https://ratings.fide.com/view_pgn.phtml?code=55964), by using [CQL 6](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/). In the game in question black's last 2 moves are not so much idiotic because mate in a few moves was inevitable either way but the use of the CQL query in the answer is a good idea for finding more such games.

Comment: I *knew* it would exist here...and had it been tagged with "selfmate", I also would have found it. (Done!)